# Concurrent datastructure modification

Tags: data-structures, concurrency

Given sets `A`, `B`, `C` with a parent-child (one to many) relationship between `A` and `B`, and `B` and `C`.

There are concurrent attempts to modify the data.
Each concurrent modification has access to `(a1, a2)` in `(A, A)` different from all other modification attempts and `a1 != a2`. Each concurrent modification may change the parent of `B* = children(a1) U children(a2)` to `a1` or `a2`.
And the `children(b1)`, for any `b1` in `B*`, to any `b2` in `B*`.

Is the following locking strategy correct with this definition? Is there any interleaving order I may have missed that leads to incorrect behaviour?

```
select (c1, c2) in (C, C), where c1 != c2:
a1 = parent(parent(c1))
a2 = parent(parent(c2))

if try_lock(a1):
    if parent(parent(c1)) is a1:    <-- Reasoning below about this
        if try_lock(a2):
            if (parent(parent(c2)) is a2:
                do a modification on (a1, a2)
        unlock(a2)
    unlock(a1)
```

My reason on that no locks are needed on items in `B` or `C`:

Any attempt at modification of `parent(parent(c1))` needs to have a lock on both the pre- and post- modified value. We currently have a lock on 'a1'. Thus no other modification attempt can change `parent(parent(c1))` to or from `a1`. So if we get that `parent(parent(c1))` is `a1` it cannot be changed to or from that value by another thread since the moment we got the lock on `a1`.